HRSCumulativeMultiplier Factorization didn't give expected result
I have:

Two 8-qubit multiplication operands
One 8-qubit multiplication result
One 1-qubit aux

I initialize all operands in superposition with Hadamard gate, then I marked expected result which is 180 or 1011 0100 in binary with Multi-Controlled Z. Then the last, Diffuser is performed for amplify expected result. And then measure_all() quantum register.

Filtering amplitude (shot) greater than 1, got following result:



index
A
B
Result
Aux
Shots




0
6
43
1
1
2


1
4
33
9
1
2


2
0
7
0
1
2


3
98
7
13
0
2


4
2
51
7
0
2


5
34
13
8
0
2


6
107
4
14
1
2


7
13
244
4
0
2


8
108
49
1
1
2


9
15
184
14
1
2


10
72
67
0
0
2


11
10
3
11
0
2


12
75
72
8
1
2


13
72
98
10
1
2


14
11
58
7
1
2


15
38
54
8
0
2



As you see, I didn't see expected result which is 180. Even, multiplication result seems not reflect with its operands which are the factors except at index 2 where 0*7=0.
Here is the following code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister,
from qiskit.circuit.library import HRSCumulativeMultiplier,

# Define quantum registers
first_operand = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'operand_a')
second_operand = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'operand_b')
multiplication_result = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'result')
aux = QuantumRegister(1, 'aux')

qc = QuantumCircuit(first_operand, second_operand, multiplication_result, aux)

# All Superposition
qc.h(first_operand)
qc.h(second_operand)
# qc.barrier()

expected_result = '10110100' # 180 in decimal
print(f'Expected: {expected_result}')

# Multiplier
multiplier = HRSCumulativeMultiplier(num_state_qubits=n_bit, num_result_qubits=n_bit)
qc.append(multiplier, qargs=list(first_operand) + list(second_operand) + list(multiplication_result) + list(aux))
qc.barrier()

for i, v in enumerate(expected_result[::-1]):
  if v == '0':
    qc.x(multiplication_result[i])
qc.barrier()

qc.h(multiplication_result[-1])
qc.mcx(multiplication_result[:-1], multiplication_result[-1])
qc.h(multiplication_result[-1])
qc.barrier()

for i, v in enumerate(expected_result[::-1]):
  if v == '0':
    qc.x(multiplication_result[i])
qc.barrier()

# Diffuser
qc.h(first_operand)
qc.h(second_operand)
qc.h(multiplication_result)
qc.h(aux)
# qc.barrier()
qc.x(first_operand)
qc.x(second_operand)
qc.x(multiplication_result)
qc.x(aux)
qc.barrier()
qc.h(aux)
qc.mcx(list(range(n_bit*3)), aux)
qc.h(aux)
qc.barrier()
qc.x(first_operand)
qc.x(second_operand)
qc.x(multiplication_result)
qc.x(aux)
# qc.barrier()
qc.h(first_operand)
qc.h(second_operand)
qc.h(multiplication_result)
qc.h(aux)

qc.measure_all()

display(qc.draw('mpl'))

And here is the raw output for shots greater than 2:
{'1000000010000011000101011': 2,
 '1000010010000010000100001': 2,
 '1000000000000000000000111': 2,
 '0000011010110001000000111': 2,
 '0000001110000001000110011': 2,
 '0000010000010001000001101': 2,
 '1000011100110101100000100': 2,
 '0000001000000110111110100': 2,
 '1000000010110110000110001': 2,
 '1000011100000111110111000': 2,
 '0000000000100100001000011': 2,
 '0000010110000101000000011': 2,
 '1000010000100101101001000': 2,
 '1000010100100100001100010': 2,
 '1000001110000101100111010': 2,
 '0000010000010011000110110': 2}

I expect, it supposed to return the factors of 180 like 2*90, 4*45, and so on...


The diffuser should only be applied to your operand registers.

(1,180), (2,90), (3,60), (4,45), (5,36), (6,30), (9,20), (10,18), (12,15) are the 9 possible ways ways you can factorize 180, but you can get each of these combinations on either the first operand or the second operand, so there's a total of 18 “conventional” solutions. Furthermore, as @egretta-thula mentioned, this a modulo N multiplier, so there will be even more solutions satisfying $ (a \times b) \text{ mod } 2^8 = 180$.

Since you are marking a few solutions out of a total of $N = 2^{(8+8)} = 65536$ superposition items, you might need to apply the oracle+diffuser in Grover’s algorithm more than just once. You need roughly $\lfloor\ \pi/4 \sqrt(N/M) \rfloor$ times, where $M$ are the possible solutions. So keep this in mind to pick how many iterations you need.

You won’t get the solution with 100% probability, so you need many more shots to maximize the chances of seeing the right results.

One thing I forgot to note before is that, as @egretta-thula also pointed out, you need to perform the uncomputation of the multiplier. I mentioned to you in a separate post that this uncomputation step is a very important for the algorithm to work correctly.


Here is an example for a smaller number of qubits ($n = 5$). The oracle is marking number $21$, for which the possible pairs that meet the condition $(a \times b) \text{ mod } 2^5 = 21$ are: $(1, 21), (3, 7), (5, 17), (7, 3), (9, 13), (11, 31), (13, 9), (15, 27), (17, 5), (19, 23), (21, 1), (23, 19), (25, 29), (27, 15), (29, 25), (31, 11).$
Since there are a total of $2^{(5+5)} = 1024$ superposition states, and a total of $16$ possible solutions, you need to apply $\lfloor\ \pi/4 \sqrt(1024/16) \rfloor = 6$ iterations.
# imports
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, transpile
from qiskit.circuit.library import HRSCumulativeMultiplier
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

sim = AerSimulator()

expected_result = '10101'     # 21 in decimal
n_bit = len(expected_result)  # number of qubits
print(f'Expected: {expected_result}')

# function to mark element
def mark_elem(expected_result):
    
    n = len(expected_result)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n, name=' Mark Elem')
    
    for i, v in enumerate(expected_result[::-1]):
        if v == '0':
            qc.x(i)
    qc.barrier()

    qc.h(n-1)
    qc.mcx(list(range(n-1)), n-1)
    qc.h(n-1)
    qc.barrier()
    
    for i, v in enumerate(expected_result[::-1]):
        if v == '0':
            qc.x(i)
    
    return qc

# function for diffuser
def diffuser(n):
    
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n, name=' Diffuser')
    qc.h(range(n))

    # qc.barrier()
    qc.x(range(n))
    qc.barrier()
    qc.h(n-1)
    qc.mcx(list(range(n-1)),n-1)
    qc.h(n-1)
    qc.barrier()
    qc.x(range(n))
    # qc.barrier()
    qc.h(range(n))
    
    return qc

# multipler gate
multiplier = HRSCumulativeMultiplier(num_state_qubits=n_bit, num_result_qubits=n_bit)


# Define quantum registers
first_operand = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'operand_a')
second_operand = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'operand_b')
multiplication_result = QuantumRegister(n_bit, 'result')
aux = QuantumRegister(1, 'aux')

first_meas = ClassicalRegister(n_bit,'a_m')
second_meas = ClassicalRegister(n_bit,'b_m')

qc = QuantumCircuit(first_operand, second_operand, multiplication_result, aux, first_meas, second_meas)

# initialize operands in superposition
qc.h(first_operand)
qc.h(second_operand)

# iterate to apply oracle+diffuser
for i in range(6):
    qc.append(multiplier, qargs=list(first_operand) + list(second_operand) + list(multiplication_result) + list(aux))
    qc.append(mark_elem(expected_result),multiplication_result)
    qc.append(multiplier.inverse(), qargs=list(first_operand) + list(second_operand) + list(multiplication_result) + list(aux))
    qc.append(diffuser(2*n_bit),range(2*n_bit))

qc.barrier()
qc.measure(first_operand,first_meas)
qc.measure(second_operand,second_meas)

# transpile, run sim, extract results
qc_t = transpile(qc,sim)

counts = sim.run(qc_t, shots=2**14).result().get_counts()
counts_new = {str(int(key[0:n_bit+1],2))+' '+str(int(key[n_bit+1:],2)): value for key, value in counts.items()}

plot_histogram(counts_new, figsize=(30,5))


Here's how the circuit looks like:

And this is the plot of the results:

As you can see, the 16 expected solutions are correctly amplified.

Is my oracle correct? Or how I marked solution (multiplication result) is correct?

Unfortunately no. See my edits above regarding uncomputation.

You need ... where M are possible solution. But, total of possible M is known in Quantum Computer Runtime, isn't it? Is it classical computer job to know M?

That’s a great question @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira. In general, you don’t know what M is, so you need another algorithm to find it. A popular one is quantum counting, but there are other methods like fixed-point quantum search

Is it practically possible running two quantum programs in one ISA quantum circuit where the first program is finding the M value, then the value will be used for iteration of HRSMultiplier factorization's Grover iteration? I mean, since iteration is happened in transpilation time, not quantum run time.


In Grover's algorithm, we use oracle to mark the state we are looking for. In your case we are looking for the numbers $x$, $y$ such that $x \times y = 180$. So, you need a multiplier. However, once you get the multiplication result you should undo the multiplier effect. Otherwise, the oracle will not be a proper Grover oracle.
So, your oracle should look like:



By setting the value of num_result_qubits to $8$ in HRSCumulativeMultiplier constructor, you do multiplication modulo $2^8$. So, your oracle will not match $1 \times 180, 2 \times 90, 3 \times 60, ..., 60 \times 3, 90 \times 2$, and $180 \times 1$ only. It will also match any two 8-digit numbers whose multiplication modulo $2^8$ equals $180$ such as $58 \times 34$.

The two operands form the search space. The result register is auxiliary. You should apply the diffuser to the two operands only.




The range of all possible values for the two operands is the search space. So, you are searching in a $2^{16}$ possible values. One iteration is not enough as @diemilio already mentioned in his answer.


So if I set num_result_qubits to 2 * num_state_qubits, I will not encounter overflow that lead me to evaluate modulo of multiplication result?

Yes! And note that, this is the default value. So, you can simply remove num_result_qubits parameter. Note, however, that you will need to add n_bit leading zeros to expected_result.
